# Grommet Starter has Errors with hot-update.js

Tags: reactjs, grommet

I'm working through the [starter example](https://github.com/grommet/grommet-starter-new-app) for Grommet and hitting this error when I add in the `<AppBar>` tag:

```
defaultValidatorFn is not a function
TypeError: defaultValidatorFn is not a function
    at shouldForwardProp (http://localhost:3000/main.c6cdacb143c3e873b1fb.hot-update.js:4491:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.c6cdacb143c3e873b1fb.hot-update.js:11014:142
    at D (http://localhost:3000/main.c6cdacb143c3e873b1fb.hot-update.js:11023:6)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31049:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33620:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35667:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20641:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20685:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20742:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40616:11)
```

On further inspection, the console shows a bunch of warnings like the following:

```
styled-components: it looks like an unknown prop "full" is being sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error
```

I tried `yarn add @emotion/is-prop-valid` but that didn't make any difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17):

One of the steps is to add `styled-components` to the dependencies. The newest major version is 6, but Grommet is currently only compatible with 5. I changed the version to `^5.3.11` in `package.json` and that solved the problem.

Comment: Changing styled-components version to `^5.3.11` does not work for me. For context, my Grommet version is `^2.34.1`

Answer (score 2):

yarn add styled-components@5.3.5 works for me. I am using "grommet": "^2.34.2"

refer: from grommet site https://github.com/grommet/grommet#install

> NOTE: Currently Grommet is only compatible with styled-components v5. We are actively working to add support for v6